# Laravel 8 default root route not working after route:cache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

Getting this error when accessing default '/' route on laravel 8 after doing route:cache

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.
```

Any idea why? all routes except this one is working :D

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
  return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

even api.php route is working.

can't find any solution online.

Thank you

Comment: clear the route `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Check your `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` (or similar) and check how the generated cached route looks like in case there's any issues. Might be worth also sharing how it looks like here.

Comment: `php artisan route:cache` does not work with Closures.

Comment: that's it `php artisan route:clear` did the trick.

thank you